# CSS stylesheet not connecting properly to ejs files

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

I have my css file in a public folder that has a css folder within it. I have tried to link to my css stylesheet in my partials and elsewhere and it isn't connecting. Here is part of my app.js file.

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/public", express.static("public"));
```

And this is the line I'm using to link to the stylesheet from multiple ejs files and files inside my partials:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `app.use("/public", express.static("public"));`, put `public/` before `/css/style.css`
There's an example on https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

`app.use('/static', express.static('public'))`

`http://localhost:3000/static/css/style.css`